# How to keep more than 1 image on the same line when resizing with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. I got this code

```
<div class="row-fluid inline">
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img823/3578/lnrk.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img593/2931/5mzt.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img841/6476/bk2j.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img823/3578/lnrk.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img593/2931/5mzt.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img841/6476/bk2j.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row-fluid inline">
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img823/3578/lnrk.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img593/2931/5mzt.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img841/6476/bk2j.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img823/3578/lnrk.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img593/2931/5mzt.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
    <div class="img-responsive span2 p-10"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img841/6476/bk2j.jpg" alt="Responsive image"/></div>
</div>
```

It shows 2 rows of 6 columns/images. When I resize it to a certain point, it shows multiple rows of 1 image. Instead, I would like to have 4 rows of 3 images/columns. Is there a simple way to do this with bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the display of the each image wrapper div is 'block', when you set to inline it gets the way you want. take alook:
(breaking into the size you want with a different code -  http://bootply.com/94383 ) (with the same code - http://bootply.com/94385)

Comment: I tried your code, but if you resize it, i have the same result. Multiple rows of 1 image.